# Pyautogui - Clicking on Virtual Machine

Tags: python, vmware, pyautogui

I am trying to automatically click on a screen of a software that is running inside a virtual machine (VMware). For test, I am using the windows calculator inside the virtual machine. The mouse pointer goes to the indicated point, but nothing happens afterwards. Apparently, no click is performed.
How could I fix it?
Here is the code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(1321,540) #here is calculator´s button 9
```

P.S.: If I run the calculator on the real machine and position it properly on the screen, the script works.

Comment: To achieve what I needed, I had to install Python and all the necessary modules inside the virtual machine. 
At first, it also did not worked inside the virtual machine, but this was solved by running "Python 3.10" (on the search bar of Windows of virtual machine) as an administrator.
Runing Python as an administrator on the real machine to click on the virtual machine did not solved my original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events might not register when using pyautogui in virtual machines due to the way it interacts with the host system.

You can try installing 3rd party virtualization software like VMWare.

If the issue persists, you might want to try a different virtualization software to see if the problem is specific to VMWare.

Hope you got the answer :)